# Using AJAX to load a folders content - Links in the folder don't have the full URL

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have folders on my web server that contain files. I used AJAX to load each folder's content onto the right pages of my website, and that's working fine, the folders content appears as links and it's great. Except one thing..

The content folders can be accessed via www.refstudio.com/Content/marketing/etc/etc which is fine, and as I said above, AJAX pulls in all the files and displays them as links, but my issue, is that each of the files in the folder that ajax pulls in seem to be linked incorrectly, so instead of the links for the files pulled in being "www.refstudio.com/Content/Marketing/design.pdf" they are only "www.refstudio.com/design.pdf" and that of course leads to a 404.

So my question is, how can I get the links to be the full/correct url in my AJAX script?

Here is my script currently, very basic and does what it has too:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ajax_link').click(function(){
   var url = $(this).attr('href');
   $('#ajax_content').load(url);
   return false;
 });
});
```

The script works just as it should, but my issue is the pulled through content links not being the full/correct URL.

Hopefully you guys can point out something I've missed!

Thanks all!

Edit: I've added an image to hopefully explain much better than I can about my issue:

[image: My Issue with AJAX]

Comment: change the url in the loaded files?

Comment: Are you using absolute path names instead of relative (do your hrefs start with `/`?)?

Comment: The image I made should explain everything, as I'm not too sure which links you are talking about, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research I managed to answer my own question! Brilliant.

I'm looping through all the links on the page that are contained within the #ajax_content element only, so as not to affect any other links on the page. I'm then adding the missing part of the URL through .attr() and then also adding in the "target" attribute to get the links to open in the pages iFrame!

I'm over the moon I managed to get it to also load in the iFrame, but ashamed that I have to use iFrames hehe.

Again, thanks for all the help guys! (especially you Alex, who spurred my brain into thinking about what you said, as I didn't quite understand what you meant at first!)

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $( ".page-id-86 .ajax-trig" ).click(function() {
        $("#ajax_content").load("http://example.com/Content/Marketing/Case_Studies/Energy/", function() {
            $("#ajax_content a").each(function() {
               var _href = $(this).attr("href");
               $(this).attr("href", "/Content/Marketing/Case_Studies/Energy/" + _href ).attr("target", "mframe");
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```